# I want to set as a callback (in App.js) for a child Button component

Tags: reactjs, class, callback

I thought is would be straight forward but its a level above my current React experience so any help appreciated.

App is a function, WorldMap is a class and so is Button

```
  import WorldMap from "./WorldMap";
  import Button from "./Button";

  function App(data) {
  ...

  {/* filterMarkers is in class comp WorldMap */}
  <WorldMap width={dimensions.widthUsed} />

  {/* i thought WorldMap.filterMarkers would work here */}
  <Button
    label="Filter by:"
    value="Brazil"
    filterBy="team1"
    groupBy="team1"
    onClickFunction={() => WorldMap.filterMarkers}
  />
  ...
  }
```

Comment: You can use context or lift the state, you can't pass a member function of a react class because you don't have the instance.

Comment: basically you need to invoke the function () => WorldMap.filterMarkers(), B U T read @HMR comment first

Comment: Thanks @HMR & roy. I guess I'm puzzled about listing the state as i'm mixing functional and class components. If I use context it seems I have to change all components?